# Count the number of times a value appears between two dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to write a formula that counts the number of times the value in cell A on Sheet 1 shows up in a column on Sheet 2, but between the enrollment date in another column on Sheet 1, and that date plus one year. I think you could use a `countifs` statement, with a edate in there, but I haven't been able to get it to work. Examples of the two sheets are below. My thinking was something like:

`=COUNTIFS('Coaching Sessions'!A:A,'Program Engagement'!A3, 'Coaching Sessions'!D:D, G2,'Coaching Sessions'!D:D, EDATE(G2, 12))`

But that returns a 0, when it should be 48 (the numbers filled in in my example below I started with criteria of `, ">=10/15/2015"` and `, "<=10/15/2016"`, but then I realized that there were different start dates. The example in the formula bar is what I'd like it to do, it obviously doesn't work right now haha.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance, have a good day.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `>=` and `<=` as strings.  The criteria in COUNTIFS resolve as strings so use `""` and `&` to concatenate

```
=COUNTIFS('Coaching Sessions'!A:A,'Program Engagement'!A3, 'Coaching Sessions'!D:D, ">=" & G2,'Coaching Sessions'!D:D, "<=" & EDATE(G2, 12))
```

Comment: Aw man that works awesome! Thanks so much :) Much appreciated. Haha such a simple answer, and I've been trying increasingly bizarre approaches. I'll keep the resolves as strings in mind next time! Thanks again, I'll resolve the question in 10 minutes, you answered too quickly!